# When using HDMI, the laptop screen extends to the TV screen

Tags: display, hdmi, display-resolution, multiple-monitors

First of all, I just want to say that using Ubuntu has been pretty frustrating, to be honest. It seems like little problems like these pop up every time I try to do anything. I guess it's just cause I'm new to using Linux, but man, I am not used to having to figure out how to do every little thing. This isn't even the first issue I had with trying to use my HDMI cord to watch some Netflix on my TV - the sound wasn't working either. Had to add myself as a user for the audio. Why I had to do that, I do not know.

Alright, sorry about the complaining. Just had to vent a little bit. Anyways, the problem I am having now is that my laptop display extends on to the TV screen. It's not very much, just a tiny line on the left side of the TV screen. But just enough to make it look bad. I've tried adjusting the resolutions and everything, didn't seem to make a difference. It goes away when I switch to mirrored display, but that makes my laptop's resolution very wonky, so I was trying to do it without mirroring it.If anyone has any suggestions on how I can fix this it would be much appreciated! I am also having problems with my speakers not working on my laptop, but I don't know if that is Ubuntu's fault or the laptop's speakers are just broken, so we'll just focus on my display issue.

Thanks!

[Side of my TV screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbQy5.jpg)

This shows the side of my TV screen. As you can see, there is a small white line on the side. This line is just an extension of my laptop screen. I don't know why my laptop screen is bleeding over on to my TV screen. If I go to a lower resolution for the laptop, this does not happen. However, when I go to a lower resolution, the laptop screen becomes blurry. Is there no way to remove the line while still maintaining a clear image on my laptop?

Comment: Hey ! Add a screenshot or take the picture of your display , it will  make the question more easy to understand . If people will be able to see what's going wrong they will be able to help you quickly .

Comment: Hey! I added a picture like you suggested! Hopefully it makes it more clear.

Comment: I have the same exact issue. It might have been related to changed display drivers when I upgraded to latest Ubuntu. It does not show on a screenshot, however, seems to be just outside the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you speakers go on your laptop, make sure you have not got a hardware mute button that is disabling them. Then check any software mute that is enabled.

Finally if all that checks out, check BIOS settings to make sure there are no speaker settings in there somewhere that need to me adjusted.

As far as display goes, try another cable - and acreen shot of what you are experiencing would help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the software mute and the BIOS settings. I don't think it's a software mute, though, because the sound check in the system settings doesn't even work.

Comment: I just looked at the BIOS settings and I don't see any speaker settings in there. Maybe I somehow disconnected the speakers when I took apart my laptop, I don't know.